# PHP Instant Message API

Tags: php, performance, api

I am creating a chat API for Android developers, but it's slow -- the chat app is getting messages a little bit late.

How can I improve the performance of my code?

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$sender_id = $_GET['sender_id'];
$receive_id = $_GET['receive_id'];

$response = array();

if($sender_id && $receive_id)
{

        $results = mysql_query("select * from cpo_chat_system where (sender_id = '$sender_id' AND receive_id = '$receive_id') union select * from cpo_chat_system where (sender_id = '$receive_id' AND receive_id = '$sender_id') ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC");
        $total_record = mysql_num_rows($results);   

        if($total_record > 0)
        {
            $response['success'] = '1';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
            {   
                $response['user'][] = $row;     
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $response['success'] = '0';
            $response['user']['error'] = "1";
            $response['user']['error_msg'] = "Not Data Found";
        }
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Have you profiled it to see where it is slow. Looking at the code I would guess it is in the database query. Once you have confirmed what is slow, let us know, and then we can help you some more.

Comment: I would really recommend escaping your $_GET strings and changing to mysqli instead of mysql (mysql is getting depricated!). `$sender_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sender_id'];` You can read more about the deprication of mysql [here](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Answer (score 2):

Before worrying about performance, you should worry about security. You are vulnerable to SQL injection. *Never* put any variables directly into queries, use prepared statements instead.

Other than that:

- `mysql_` is deprecated for quite a while, and it will be removed in future PHP versions. You really shouldn't write code using it, use `PDO` or `mysqli_` instead (and as said, with prepared statements).
- upper-case all SQL keywords in your queries to improve readability.
- your indentation is inconsistent.
- your query seems a bit off. Do you really need `union`? Shouldn't something like `WHERE (sender_id = '$sender_id' AND receive_id = '$receive_id') OR (sender_id = '$receive_id' AND receive_id = '$sender_id')` work?
- I would change the `date` and `time` columns to a `datetime` column, it should speed up your query a bit.
- `receive` should be `receiver` to fit in with `sender`.

Comment: thank you for your answer I will take care of all the points..